# HttpClient can't access site after login redirect

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, redirect, httpclient

I'm trying to access a site using HttpClient in an asp.net core 3.1 application that is redirecting me to a login page (the site I'm trying to access sits behind the login).

The login page does expose an authentication api (separate from the front end login page) which I'm hitting first and using cookie container. Does anyone know how I can proceed past the login page? This is the code I'm using:

```
  public class ApplicationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static CookieContainer cookieContainer;
        private static HttpClientHandler clienthandler;
        private HttpClient client;


        public ApplicationController(ILogger<ApplicationController> logger)
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetAsync()
        {
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            clienthandler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true, 
                     UseCookies = true, CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
            client = new HttpClient(clienthandler);

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent("{\"username\": \"account@widget.com\" + 
             ,\"password\": \"Password$6\"}");

            // I can successfully login here and get a 200 back
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://widgets.okta.com/api/v1/authn", httpContent).Result;

            // This call redirects to the login page and returns a 200 success, even though it doesn't actually log in nor can I access my website
            var siteResponse = client.PostAsync("https://siteinterestedin.com", httpContent).Result;
```

Comment: What kind of authentication does the site use? You mentioned it exposes an authentication API.

Comment: I provide the username and password in a JSON in the body of the POST request. I followed this:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authn/#request-example-for-primary-authentication-with-public-application

Comment: Is this a short-lived request - ie you open this httpClient once to navigate somewhere and that's it? If so, you need to set the HttpClient's headers to Okta's expected values from the successful login. If not, you'll want to look into Microsofts documentation on OAuth flow as your question is going to explode a bit.

Comment: you might be on to something. I used the UI to log into the portal and I grabbed the login request cookie header that was returned from the successful login, it contained FedAuth and FedAuth1 values. I then hard coded these two variables into the CookieContainer of the second request and was able to successfully download the content from the site.

Comment: The only issue now is that the account login uses 2FA so I'll need to figure out how to log into the account programatically by bypassing 2FA somehow, but that's a different issue from the one I posted about here. Thanks!